# What was the special reason?

Tags: plot-explanation, hachi-a-dogs-tale

In the movie [*Hachi: A Dog's Tale*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1028532/), the Japanese college professor Ken advises Parker that the dog Hachi will fetch him the ball only for a special reason. What reason was that? And why did Hachi woof several times?

Was the dog able to make out Parker's death?

Any references to the dog are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Ken just said that Hachi will bring him the ball only for a special reason, which was also proved right when he does that by bringing the ball to Parker on the day he is going to die.

There is the theory that animals have a 6th sense. This is attributed to dogs and cats the most. It's a debatable concept and it's about beliefs. But from the movie point of view the special reason to bring the ball from Hachi is to save the life of Parker.

For the woofing, there are myths among the people that dogs woof in a different voice than usual to indicate death. But that's also debatable.